# Android WebView width

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to control the width scale of a WebView.
After spending about two full days. I'm still left where i started.
I have followed the following documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

I have experimented with the meta tags, css, WebView.setInitialScale.
Sometimes the changes makes the WebView clip the middle of the screen out, sometimes one third.
When you think you have found a predictable pattern in the madness, you find out that layout response is total random.
**Does anybody know if there is a way forward implementing embedded HTML5 web pages on the Android platform or is it just something that the Android platform isn't ready for yet?**

Comment: wait...what? Are you trying to **scale** the page, or set the webview's **width**? HTML5 and Android WebViews play nicely together in my experience.

Comment: I really have a bad experience with HTML5 and Android WebViews. Page is too large to fit in the view. There are compatibility issues in HTML5 with Android.

Comment: Same here, content-width in the viewport tag does not work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where exactly you went wrong but here's some boilerplate code I use for testing my embedded WebViews. I should mention that I mainly target Honeycomb (3.x), but you didnt' specify so:

Here's the simple sample layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Now here's the code for the Activity backer:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebViewTestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final String TAG = "webview test";

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);     

    FrameLayout vg = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout1);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);

    vg.removeAllViews();
    vg.addView(webView);

    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();           
    settings.setSupportZoom(false);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {

            Log.i(TAG, cm.messageLevel() + ": " + cm.message() + " -- From line " + cm.lineNumber() + " of " + cm.sourceId() );

            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new Object() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void foo() {
            Log.i(TAG, "----- FOO CALLED -----");
            Toast.makeText(WebViewTestActivity.this, "foo called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }, "android");

    String html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style=\"background:black;color:white;padding:20px;\"><a href=\"javascript:android.foo()\">CLICK ME!</a><div><label>HTML5 number input: <input type=number /></label></div></body></html>";
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://yourOptionalBaseUrl.com/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);   
}        
}
```

...and that's all you need to have an embedded html5 page. You can also put your html page into your "assets" folder and load it using:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page.html");
```

or embed just a single resource like

or just point it to your server using the same load URL syntax from before

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.yourpage.com/android?param=custom");
```

... i hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the example ckozl
My target device is 2.3.3 App level 10
I tried your example. The scale is still the same.
Everything its stretched 100%
When using the asset folder instead of the sddisk all my css and js references are broken.
Btw. is there any particular reason to use FrameLayout instead of WebView?

Comment: wait...what? Are you trying to scale the page, or set the webview's width?

I'm simply trying to get my page stretch to the entire width of my phone device, just as it already does in FF, Chrome and IE9 on my laptop.
I would be insanely happy if i could just have this to html to work.
<html><body><img src="smilie" style="position:relative;width:100%"></body></html>
Unfortunately i only get to see about one quarter of the img. the rest is cropped.
Unless i specify the content width to an exact value, which is a no go.

Comment: I used a `FrameLayout` as placeholder, the purpose of the code originally was used to test things on a `WebView` that was dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

I have reached the conclusion that the only way to modify the WebView width is to manipulate the target-densitydpi found in the html meta tag

By setting the target-densitydpi to my device width i get the web page to span the entire width of the screen.
By creating the html file at runtime i can fill in the target-densitydpi with the detected device width. Yikes!!